# Angular JS promises and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 questions. What I'm doing is asking for a postcode, getting a latitude and longitude of that postcode using an API and then using that latitude and longitude to get all street level crimes on a particular date near that location using UK police API. 
The problem is ng-repeat doesn't work and I guess this is because when the page is loaded the $http request is still hasn't received anything back because if I console log it returns undefined and then after that use setTimeout for two seconds it returns what I need.

Here's my code:

```
function PostCodeCtrl($scope, Server, $location, $routeParams){

this.postcode = $routeParams.postcode;

if(this.postcode){
    this.title = "dasdasd";
    this.crimes = undefined;

    Server.get("http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/" + this.postcode)
        .then(function(response){

        this.response = response.data;

        if(response.data.status === 200){

            Server.get('http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat='+ 
                        this.response.result.latitude +
                        '&lng='+
                        this.response.result.longitude+
                        '&date=2013-01').then(function(response){

                this.crimes = response.data;

            });

        }

    });

    console.log(this.crimes); //returns undefined
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(this.crimes); //returns JSON object
    }, 2000);
}else{

    $location.path('/');

}
```

}

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="crime in postcode.crimes">
        {{crime.category}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I also don't understand the point of promises, after looking at at least 5 screencasts and presentations on youtube they all say that promises help get rid of the pyramid code aka something like this:

```
(function($) {
  $(function(){
    $("button").click(function(e) {
      $.get("/test.json", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $(".list").each(function() {
          $(this).click(function(e) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              alert("Hello World!");
            }, 1000);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

but I don't see it helping you still have to nest things in thens like in my first example and it still creates the pyramid structure.

Comment: it seems like you're using 'controller as' but your html does not reflect that. You're populating THIS instead of $scope

Comment: your console logs are trying to access the data before it has been retrieved, also not a good idea to use `this` within the closures

Comment: goreorto, I defined it in my routes provider, that is not the problem.

Comment: Then you're missing the controller name part in your view `ctrl.postcode.crimes` don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two questions here, so let's break it down.

**How to load async data in `ng-repeat`**

Given the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  {{item.title}}
</div>
```

If `$scope.items` is set asyncronously, then `ng-repeat` will not render anything until you set the `$scope.items` to some array - then Angular would detect the change and update the View:

```
$http.get("data.json").then(function(response){
   $scope.items = response.data; // data is the array of items
});

console.log($scope.items); // undefined, since $http has not yet received the reponse
```

**How to chain promises without "callback hell"**

Promises are chain-able - where each `.then` handler returns either the data or another promise of the data to the next guy in the line:

```
$http.get("/someService")
  .then(function(response){
     var data = response.data;
     return // important!
       $http.get("/someOtherService", { d: data });
  })
  .then(function(response){
    var data2 = response.data;

    // do something

    return finalData;
  };
```

You can see how it chains. If you put all of this in your service:

```
.factory("Svc", function($http){
    getFinalData: function(){
       return $http.get("/someService")
         // etc.. (as above)
    }
})
```

Then in the controller, you can just do:

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function(Svc){
   Svc.getFinalData().then(function(data){
     $scope.items = data; // could be used with ng-repeat
   });
});
```